# need to convert promise value in chai-as-promised expression

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai

I have a promise that resolves to an object. This object has a method `.toString` that I need to test against. So my expression below fails because the promise is an object and I am comparing it to a string:

```
chai.expect(mypromise).to.eventually.be.equal('1.4')
```

I need to call `mypromise.toString()` and use it somewhere before the control gets to `equal('1.4')`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
chai.expect(mypromise.toString()).to.eventually.be.equal('1.4')
```

**Edit:**

Ohh, I see what you mean. In this case, the best way to take care of this is to put your expect inside a `then` statement, like so:

```
mypromise.then(function (result) {
    return result.toString();
}).to.eventually.be.equal('1.4');
```

I *think* that should work, but I haven't been able to test it out.

Comment: yeah, that's still doesn't compare 2 promises. What if instead of "1.4" you need to have to compare to a value that comes out of a promise as well? You can of course use `then` but that's kinda ugly, isn't it?